# Measure Theory Problem: Prove a measurable function is a constant

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking for good solutions to this problem. Could you please help me with this? Any solution would be appreciated.

Let $\mathscr{G}$ be the smallest $\sigma-algebra$ on $\mathbb{R}$ containing all single points.
Let f(x) be a function that is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{G}$, that is, for any Borel set B on $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathscr{G}$.

Show that there is a countable set A on $\mathbb{R}$ such that f is a constant on $\overline{A}$ (the complement of A).

Comment: Do you know which sets are in $\mathcal{G}$? How do they look like (resp. which specific property do they have)? If you do not know the answer to these questions, then a first step would be to search for "co-countable sigma-algebra" ...

Comment: Thank you. $\mathscr{G}$ is the collection of all subsets $\mathit{A}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathit{A}$ or its complement is countable.

Comment: Consider the sets $f^{-1}(\{x\})$. Can they all be countable?